# Updating a text field dynamically using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my first attempt at using jQuery. I'm attempting to implementing a basic finance calculator.

I'm using jQuery UI range sliders. The script for these is as follows:

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
    $( "#slider-deposit" ).slider({
      value: 100,
      min: <?php echo json_encode($minDeposit); ?>,
      max: <?php echo json_encode($maxDeposit); ?>,
      step: 1,
      slide: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#amount-deposit" ).val( "" + ui.value );
      }
    });
    $( "#amount-deposit" ).val( "" + $( "#slider-deposit" ).slider( "value" ) );
  });  

    jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
        $( "#slider-payback" ).slider({
      value:100,
      min: 12,
      max: 36,
      step: 12,
      slide: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#payback-period" ).val( "" + ui.value );
      }
    });
    $( "#payback-period" ).val( "" + $( "#slider-payback" ).slider( "value" ) );
  });
```

I also have several text fields on the page, I'm attempting to update these text fields dynamically as the values of the range sliders change on the page.

Here's one text field ax an exmaple:

```
<input type="text" id="monthly-repayments" readonly style="border:0; color:#f6931f;">
```

What is the best way to ad a value to these text fields and change it dynamically as the values of the sliders change?

Thanks

Here is the full html:

```
  <div>
    <label for="amount-depoist">Deposit amount:</label>
    <input type="text" id="amount-deposit" readonly style="border:0; color:#f6931f;">
    <div id="slider-deposit"></div>
</div>

<div>
  <label for="payback-period">Payback Period:</label>
  <input type="text" id="payback-period" readonly style="border:0; color:#f6931f;">
<div id="slider-payback"></div>
<div>

<div>
    <label for="apr_rate">APR:</label>
    <input type="text" id="apr_rate" readonly style="border:0; color:#f6931f;">
</div>

<div>
    <label for="monthly-repayments">Monthly Payments:</label>
    <input type="text" id="monthly-repayments" readonly style="border:0; color:#f6931f;">
</div>

<div>
    <label for="total_payable">Total Payable:</label>
    <input type="text" id="total_payable" readonly style="border:0; color:#f6931f;">
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you create a JSfiddle?

Comment: Sure, might take me a few minutes

Comment: Just because you ask the best way. I'll recommend you to use angular js, because it is design to support two way binding. Look like it suit your requirment

Comment: What script does your browser see, because I'm certain that it *doesn't* – and certainly shouldn't – see any of the `<?php...?>` statements; what values do those calls resolve to?

Comment: Sorry, there are some php elements I left out because I didn't think they were necessary . I can add them in in an edit if you like? They are just integer values that I'm passing in to the script.

Answer (score 1):

Add an extra function in the slide event change function so that it updates the value of the input field - i.e. something like this:

Change:

```
  slide: function( event, ui ) {
    $( "#payback-period" ).val( "" + ui.value );
  }
```

to

```
  slide: function( event, ui ) {
    $( "#payback-period" ).val( "" + ui.value );
    $('#monthly-repayments').val( "" + ui.value );
  }
```

This should update the value of the `#monthly-repayments` input form each time the value of the slider changes

Comment: Ok thanks, how might I do some arithmetic against these values though? For example how might I get the value of 'amount-deposit' and multiply it by 'monthly-repayments' in that slide function event. Thanks

Comment: @LiamFell are `amount-deposit` and `monthly-repayments` JS variables or do you need to parse them from somewhere?

Comment: They are JS variables. Thanks

Comment: `var total = amount-deposit * monthly-repayments` and then update the following: `$('#monthly-repayments').val( total )`

Comment: Was that what you wanted?

Comment: It is, I'm just unsure how to implement that in the code. Sorry

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95869/discussion-between-ismail-m-and-liam-fell).

Comment: @LiamFell, update the exemplar code snippet, with these variables and also add the corresponding HTML for the all the elements used in this JS snippet & I'll have a look.